# Delete node.js events, listeners goes away too?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, eventemitter

If I delete a node.js event, the listeners go away too right? I don't have to delete anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean deleting an EventEmitter instance? (or, equally, an Object that inherits from EventEmitter?)

In this case I think that each listener would be deleted as well when you delete the object instance, they're part of the object instance

Comment: yeah. OK, so that's good. Thanks. I hope this is correct, nobody else is disagreeing. Too lazy to view source.